# xgb.cv's auc score is not matching with cross_val_score when `colsample_bytree` is other than 1

Tags: python, cross-validation, xgboost, k-fold, xgbclassifier

I am working on highly imbalanced dataset. During hyperparameter tuning, I found that if `colssample_bytree` is **set to value other than 1**, then `cross_val_score` from sklearn package is not matching with the auc score obtained from `xgb.cv`.

**xgb.cv code:**

```
# creating kfolds
kfolds = StratifiedKFold(n_splits = 5, shuffle = True, random_state = 16)

# creating model object and using it for xgb.cv
xgb0 = XGBClassifier(objective= 'binary:logistic', n_estimators =2, colsample_bytree = 0.6, 
random_state =16, n_jobs = -1, eval_metric = 'auc')
params = xgb0.get_params()
xg_train = xgb.DMatrix(X_train_p.values, label = y_train.values)
cv_result = xgb.cv(params, xg_train, num_boost_round=2, folds = kfolds, metrics = 'auc', early_stopping_rounds = 50, 
                   as_pandas = True, seed = 16,stratified=True, shuffle = True)
print(cv_result['test-auc-mean'].values[-1])
```

This results in  test-auc-mean of 0.91706

**cross_val_score code:**

```
cv_score = cross_val_score(xgb0, X_train_p, y_train, cv = kfolds, n_jobs = -1, scoring = 'roc_auc')
cv_score.mean()
```

This results in  test-auc-mean of 0.8994

I don't understand this huge difference between these and as I already indicated if `colsample_bytree` is set to 1 then there is no difference between scores. Also this difference between `auc` scores increase significantly as we decrease `colsample_bytree`.

Can someone help me in understanding why this is happening. Thanks